# How do I remove a commit before a push?

Tags: git, github

So I was pushing a commit and github warned me about a video file that exceeded its maximum MB, so then I deleted the file from the videos folder, made another commit stating "removed heavy video" and pushed commit, but it's pushing both commits, the one with the video still and the one without and i only want to commit the last one. Can someone help?

I tried deleting the last commit but I didn't want to risk losing the progress I had until then so I dont know what to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 0):

Rebase starting at a certain commit:

```
git rebase -i <sha1-commit-hash>
```

The interactive prompt will then show each successive commit made after the one entered in the command. By entering `drop` you can remove a commit from the history.

See [Git - Re-writing History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for more info.

Comment: Note, though, that `drop` removes *all* changes that the commit introduces, not only a single file.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard <commit_hash>
git push origin -f
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**